# Excel VBA - Search Range - If Cell Contains Text Then Copy Cell - Paste Offset 2,1

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to simplify an excel sheet I work with on a weekly basis.

I'm trying to create a VBA Macro that would do the following:

1. Search Column C for any Cells that contain Text, If Blank Ignore It
2. If text is found in a Cell, Copy That Cell, Paste the Contents Offset (2,1)

Any help anyone can give me, I would greatly appreciate. I have searched for other macros and have attempted to modify them for my use to no avail.

```
    **Example Before Macro**
  A       B       C       D       E
1                 Hi
2                 Test
3
4                 Done
5
6

**Example After Macro Has Been Run**
  A       B       C       D       E
1                 Hi
2                 Test
3                         Hi
4                 Done    Test
5
6                         Done
```

Current Code:

```
Sub CopyC()  
  Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range 
  Set SrchRng = Range("C1:C10") 

  For Each cel In SrchRng 
    If InStr(1, cel.Value) > 0 Then 
      cel.Offset(2, 1).Value = "-" 
    End If 
  Next cel 
End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like this would be a simple For loop and If statement.  What code do you currently have/have you tried?

Comment: 'code'Sub CopyC()

Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set SrchRng = Range("C1:C10")

For Each cel In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value) > 0 Then
        cel.Offset(2, 1).Value = "-"
    End If
Next cel

End Sub'code'

Comment: Change your if statement to `If cel.Value <> "" Then`

Comment: And `cel.Offset(2, 1).Value = "-" ` to `cel.Offset(2, 1).Value = cel.value`

Comment: @ScottCraner I changed the code to that; However, it only copies a blank text (That is because of my code, I do not know how to copy the cell's contents) and it does NOT ignore blank cells.

Comment: @ScottCraner Almost there!!!! Thank you!!! How can I get it to ignore blank cells now, it is almost 100%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are Close:

```
Sub CopyC()
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Set SrchRng = Range("C1:C10")
For Each cel In SrchRng
    If cel.Value <> "" Then
        cel.Offset(2, 1).Value = cel.Value
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

[image]

I added 1-6 in column D to show that it is ignoring the blanks

Comment: Scott you are a genius! I love you :D <3